# Android Get result from activity in another activity than the one that launched it

Tags: android

I am programming an app in Android. I have a FirstActivity that launches a SecondActivity that then launches a ThirdActivity. How can I get the result from ThirdActivity in FirstActivity, when ThirdActivity was launched by SecondActivity?
Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: If you're doing this "manually", you can use [`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT) on the launch `Intent` in `SecondActivity`. I have no idea if or how the new Activity Result API does it.

Comment: Perhaps these should not be separate activities. Instead, perhaps you should use a single activity, with fragments or composables for individual screens.